# Solving Python Riddle

Tags: python, python-3.x

Problem I am supposed to solve:
The Riddler is planning his next caper somewhere on
Pennsylvania Avenue.  The address on Pennsylvania is a four-digit number with
the following properties.

All four digits are different,
The digit in the thousands place is three times the digit in the tens place,
The number is odd, and
The sum of the digits is 27.

So I made a for loop that checks each four digit integer and puts the value in a place holder (i.e. thousands, hundreds, etc.) And conditional if statements to fit the conditions. But my problem is that the IDE gives me no error when I run the code, but it does not print my statement at the end. I'm having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my code.

```
address = 0                     
thousand = 0
hundred = 0
ten = 0
one = 0

for address in range(1000,9999+1):

    thousand = (address/1000)%10    
    hundred = (address/100)%10
    ten = (address/10)%10
    one = (address%10)

if (thousand != hundred) and (thousand != ten) and (thousand != one) and (hundred != ten) and (hundred != one) and (ten !=one):
    if thousand == (3*ten):
        if one % 2 != 0:
            if thousand+hundred+ten+one == 27:
                print("The address is: ",address, "Pennsylvania Ave.")
```

It runs but the print statement does not show up.

Comment: The indent of code is very important in python. Please post your correct code including correct indent.

Comment: The code I posted has the correct indenting, I tried copying and pasting the code I posted on the form and it gives me no errors. It gives me the same result, no print statement

Comment: Your `if` statement is outside of your `for` loop, so you are not testing all the addresses (you are only testing 9999). Also, you need to add `int` to your calculations, like `thousand = int(address/1000)%10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All four digits are different, The digit in the thousands place is three times the digit in the tens place, The number is odd, and The sum of the digits is 27.

- The digit in the thousands place is three times the digit in the tens place: valid combos are 3x1x, 6x2x, 9x3x.
- The sum of the digits is 27: only 9x3x is possible since 27 - (6 + 2) > 8+7, the maximum remaining digits. In fact 27 - (9 + 3) = 15. The remaining digits can be 9,6 or 8,7
- All four digits are different: 9,5 is not an option. The number is either 9837 or 9738.
- The number is odd: it's **9837**.

Some pencil and paper works better than a `for` loop here.

That being said, keep in mind that `/` is the true division operator in Python 3, irrespective of type. So when `address = 6754`, for example

```
thousand = (address / 1000) % 10
```

evaluates as

```
thousand = 6.754 % 10
```

which is just `6.754`, not `6` as you were probably hoping. To get `6`, use the integer division operator `//`:

```
thousand = (address // 1000) % 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## Number Theory

```
isop = []

for a in range(1, 10, 1):
    for b in range(0, 10, 1):
        for c in range(0, 10, 1):
            for d in range(0, 10, 1):
                if a!=b and a!=c and a!=d and b!=c and b!=d and c!=d:
                    sum = a+b+c+d
                    if a==3*c and sum == 27:
                        num = a*1000 + b*100 + c*10 + d
                        if num % 2 == 1:
                            isop.append(num)
for i in range(len(isop)):
    print(isop[i])
```